# Python terminology- what are the extra REPL outputs called?

Tags: python, read-eval-print-loop

Consider the following code:

```py
class Greet:
    def __init__(self, greeting='Hello'):
        print(greeting)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  print('Initializing and assigning')
  greet = Greet('Shalom!')
  print('Only initializing a class')
  Greet()
```

If I run the script, I get the output:

```
Initializing and assigning
Shalom!
Only initializing a class
Hello
```

However, say I'm running the above code in an interactive REPL, the interaction is as follows:

```py
In 1> greet = Greet('Shalom!')
Shalom!
In 2> Greet()
Hello
<__main__.Greet object at 0x7fac80cc84c0>
```

If you notice, in the second input i.e. `Greet()`, I get a second line which is I believe `repr` of the object that results in the *evaluation* of the input. What is this EXTRA output called? Because it seems to me that it's a quirk of the REPL itself.

Comment: In the interactive shell, any expressions (not assignments) evaluating to a non-`None` value will be printed. This does not happen in scripts. You are seeing this output in addition to the actual `print` statements. If you had put instead `greet2 = Greet()` then you wouldn't have seen this.

Comment: Thanks. That answers it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying the actual answer from the comments above:

> In the interactive shell, any expressions (not assignments) evaluating
> to a non-`None` value will be printed. This does not happen in
> scripts. You are seeing this output in addition to the actual print
> statements. If you had put instead `greet2 = Greet()` then you
> wouldn't have seen this.

But posting this answer in order to make an additional comment that doesn't fit into the comment format... you probably in any case wouldn't want to have your object perform an *action* on initialisation -- better to put that into a separate method:

```
>>> class Greeter:
...     def __init__(self, greeting='Hello'):
...         self.greeting = greeting
...     def greet(self):
...         print(self.greeting)
... 
>>> greeter = Greeter()
>>> greeter.greet()
Hello
```

You do not see any additional line here in any case, because the `greet` method returns `None`.